# Pandas df to ndjson gives incorrect line count

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, ndjson

I have a dataframe with 320 rows. I converted it to ndjson with pandas:

```
df.to_json('file.json', orient='records', lines=True)
```

However upon loading the data, I only obtain 200 rows.

```
with open('file.json') as f:
    print(len(f.readlines()))
```

gives 200

```
spark.read.json('file.json').count
```

also gives 200

Only reloading it with pandas give the correct row count:

```
pd.read_json('file.json', orient='records', lines=True)
```

My dataset contains `\n` characters in the fields. I am expecting to have as much or more lines when I load the records with python or spark.

What is the issue here with the `pandas.to_json` method?

Answer (score 0):

I manually inspected the json file line by line, and I discovered that `pandas.to_json` seems to be writing wrongly. (or I misunderstood the specifications)

```
with open('file.json') as f:
    j = f.read().replace('},{', '}\n{')
with open('file.jsonl', 'w') as f:
    f.write(j)
```

Replacing the errors in the file fixes the issues.